# Encode classifier performance in dataframe and account for NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the performance of a classifier. In one column (`c1`) there is the ground truth for that data point, whether the case is positive (`A`) or negative (`B`). In another column (`c2`) there is the classifier's response, which is either positive (`a`) or negative (`b`). I want to calculate a column that encodes the performance of the classifier according to the typical four cells of a confusion matrix (true positive, true negative, false positive, false negative).

What is the most efficient way to do this in pandas? Currently I have the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'c1': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
    'c2': ['a', 'b', np.nan, 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', np.nan, 'a']
})

data
        c1  c2
    0   A   a
    1   B   b
    2   A   NaN
    3   B   a
    4   A   b
    5   B   a
    6   B   b
    7   A   a
    8   B   NaN
    9   A   a

data.loc[(data['c1']=='A') & (data['c2']=='a'), 'class'] = 'truepos'
data.loc[(data['c1']=='A') & (data['c2']=='b'), 'class'] = 'falseneg'
data.loc[(data['c1']=='B') & (data['c2']=='a'), 'class'] = 'falsepos'
data.loc[(data['c1']=='B') & (data['c2']=='b'), 'class'] = 'trueneg'
data.loc[data['c2'].isnull(), 'class'] = np.nan
data
    c1  c2  class
0   A   a   truepos
1   B   b   trueneg
2   A   NaN NaN
3   B   a   falsepos
4   A   b   falseneg
5   B   a   falsepos
6   B   b   trueneg
7   A   a   truepos
8   B   NaN NaN
9   A   a   truepos
```

This works but I don't think it's very good because it's quite repetitive. Is there a better way? e.g. maybe some sort of lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it with a dict:

```py
matrix = {
    ("A", "a"): "truepos",
    ("A", "b"): "falseneg",
    ("B", "a"): "falsepos",
    ("B", "b"): "trueneg",
}

data["class"] = data.apply(lambda x: matrix.get((x[0], x[1]), np.nan), axis=1)
```

```py
print(data)
# Output
  c1   c2     class
0  A    a   truepos
1  B    b   trueneg
2  A  NaN       NaN
3  B    a  falsepos
4  A    b  falseneg
5  B    a  falsepos
6  B    b   trueneg
7  A    a   truepos
8  B  NaN       NaN
9  A    a   truepos
```